# Aspose.Word template foreach syntax

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I try build template in .doc file. I use mail merge to bind data. 
In my template I use field like `<<TableStart:ListData>> ... <<TableEnd:ListData>>` to building table. I now how add if statement `{IF ="True" ... }`. 
But how add foreach loop? 
In this page: [Mustache syntax](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsjava/Mail+Merge+using+%27Mustache%27+Template+Syntax) is description of mustache syntax with foreach. How add this code to template.docx ?
My c# code - it may be usefull:

```
        var document = GetDocumentFromTemplate("SystemConfigurationTemplate.docx");
        var model = BuildModel();
        var asposeDataSource = new AsposeDataSource(document, model);
        document.MailMerge.Execute(asposeDataSource);
        document.Save(stream, SaveFormat.Pdf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the following syntax in Word document:

```
{{ #foreach list }}{{ Number }}{{ /foreach list }}
```

You then need to call MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions method to see foreach tag in action. Please see following code:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("list");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Number");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    DataRow datarow = dataTable.NewRow();
    dataTable.Rows.Add(datarow);
    datarow[0] = "Number " + i.ToString();                
}

Document doc = new Document(MyDir + @"in.docx");

doc.MailMerge.UseNonMergeFields = true;
doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dataTable);

doc.Save(MyDir + @"17.8.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.